# Native module RNDatePicker tried to override RNDatePicker. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java

Tags: android, react-native, datepicker, jsx

I have used **react-native-community/datetimepicker** to implement the date picker in my project, I have no issues in iOS, but in android I have some issues in my MainApplication.java, someone help me to fix the [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxfHy.png), I have attached my MainApplication.java file here, I have tried all the possibilities I can but I am failed to fix this issue

```
package com.rndemo;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // packages.add(new RNDatePickerPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any picker libraries that depend on any date picker library and another stand alone date picker library in your project?

Comment: yes, I'm using  *react-native-community/datetimepicker* library in my project to implement the date picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following as a temporary fix:

Go to `node_modules/react-native-date-picker/android/src/main/java` and open the `DatePickerModule.java`

There you can add the following:

```
@Override    
public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
   return true;    
}
```

It should end up looking like this.

[image]

This tells Android that if it sees the same package during build it should override it and you will end up having only 1 reference of the package.

The issue should be solved. Try recompiling Android. ✅

Additionally, you can use [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package#readme) to keep this change after doing a clean (i.e. removing `node_modules` and doing a fresh install).

**To extend this answer** - this solution can be also applied to the same issue but for other libraries. The important part is to add the above code to the class that extends `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`.

So find the class that extends `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` for your specific library, add the code above, and rebuild.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps me to fix the issue thank you for the answer!